# DRY up logic to handle insert/update/delete of many to many records in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

In my application, I have a fair number of many to many relationships. I find that I'm  writing a fair bit of code that looks something like this (I have taken the example code from the Contoso sample project for ease of reference):

```
private void UpdateInstructorCourses(int[] selectedCourses, Instructor instructorToUpdate)
    {
        if (selectedCourses == null)
        {
            instructorToUpdate.Courses = new List<Course>();
            return;
        }

        var selectedCoursesHS = new HashSet<int>(selectedCourses);
        var instructorCourses = new HashSet<int>(instructorToUpdate.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID));

        foreach (var course in db.Courses)
        {
            if (selectedCoursesHS.Contains(course.CourseID))
            {
                if (!instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
                {
                    instructorToUpdate.Courses.Add(course);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
                {
                    instructorToUpdate.Courses.Remove(course);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

My many to many relationships are, by and large, composed of a central table with a lot of data and a bunch of lookup tables that have Id and Name fields.

The above is great when there's one or two many-to-manys but it gets a bit tedious and I have multiple methods which all follow the same basic logic above, but obviously use different dbsets in the foreach and a different object as the second param.

Is there a nice way to DRY the multiple methods up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a generic method along these lines (not tested, and not compiled against a real EF context)

```
private void UpdateCollection<T>(int[] selectedIds, ICollection<T> dbCollection, ICollection<T> collectionToUpdate, Func<T, int> idGetter)
{
    if (selectedIds == null)
    {
        collectionToUpdate.Clear();
        return;
    }

    var selectedIdsHS = new HashSet<int>(selectedIds);
    var idsToUpdate = new HashSet<int>(collectionToUpdate.Select(idGetter));

    foreach (var elem in dbCollection)
    {
        var id = idGetter(elem);

        if (selectedIdsHS.Contains(id))
        {
            if (!idsToUpdate.Contains(id))
            {
                collectionToUpdate.Add(elem);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (idsToUpdate.Contains(id))
            {
                collectionToUpdate.Remove(elem);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It can be invoked as follows:

```
UpdateCollection(new[] {1,2,3}, db.Courses, instructor.Courses, c => c.CourseID);
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I had to use db.Courses.ToList() when invoking, but it all hangs together beautifully.